# interact with YouTube app on android

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I would like to interact with YouTube app on android.

My app is basically a service that is running all the time.
I wanna detect if user was watching YouTube and then lock the phone, when he come back the last watched video should continue playing.

Any suggestions? Where to start?

I am thinking to implement a software touch on play button. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: This question is far too broad and includes no attempt to solve the problem.  StackOverflow is for **specific** problems.

Comment: As far as i know the youtube app already handles this functionality. As soon as you lock the phone, the youtube video stops playing and resumes once you unlock the phone.

Comment: @codedByMi, It doesn't resume, that is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can force a video:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + id));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Obtaining the Android API Key

1. First we need to get the SHA-1 fingerprint on your machine using java keytool. Execute the below command in cmd/terminal to get the SHA-1 fingerprint.
2. Go to Google Developer Console and select or create a new project.
3. On the left sidebar, select APIs under APIs & auth and turn the status ON for YouTube Data API v3.
4. On the left sidebar, select Credentials and Create new key under Public API acess.
5. When popup comes asking you to choose platform, select Android Key.
6. Paste the SHA-1 key and your project’s package name separated by semicolon(;).
7. Click on create. Now you should see the API KEY on the dashboard.

> ```
>  public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
>         YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
> ```

```
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    // YouTube player view
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

        // Initializing video player with developer key
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {

            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
            player.loadVideo(Config.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);

            // Hiding player controls
            player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }

}
```